# Can't use Subversion command line client: svn The path to the Subversion executable is probably wrong android

Tags: android, android-studio, svn

I downloaded a project from svn. When I open the project, on Android Studio, I get the following error:
Can't use Subversion command line client: svn The path to the Subversion executable is probably wrong android

However, I do not want my project to be linked to svn. How can I solve the problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, for my case.
In the grandle.properties file, I deleted the statement:
org.gradle.java.home = / usr / lib / jvm / java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64

Now, my grandle.properties file is empty and works correctly

Answer (score -1):

```
IntelliJ 14.1.5 or 15 with SVN 1.9
IntelliJ 14.1.4 with SVN 1.8
```